# how to set a border that does not affect background image

Tags: css

I know I can use `box-sizing:border-box;` to create the border inside an elements actual width, but I want my image to be not affected by the border.
example:

```
div { 
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-image:url("someplace/demo.jpg");
    background-size:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

With the codes above, the image width and height will be 98px, because border takes 1 pixel for each parallal sides.

But I want my image to still stay 100 px / 100% and border as an overlaping border on top of the image.

Is there any way to do this ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set background-size to actual size of your container.

```css
div {
  width:100px; 
  height:100px; 
  box-sizing:border-box; 
  background:url("http://lorempixel.com/100/100") center no-repeat ;
  background-size:100px 100px; 
  border:1px solid black;
}
img ~ div {
  border:15px solid rgba(100,200,0,0.5);
}
div + div {
  background-size:100%;
}
div, img {
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"/>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

I inserted image and bigger border in demo to easely see the different effects

for he outline , you will need ,outline offset

```css
div {
  width:100px; 
  height:100px; 
  box-sizing:border-box; 
  background:url("http://lorempixel.com/100/100") center no-repeat ;
  background-size:100px 100px; 
  outline:15px solid rgba(100,200,0,0.5);
  outline-offset:-15px;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

border increased to make effect obvious

or box-shadow ?

```css
div {
  width:100px; 
  height:100px; 
  box-sizing:border-box; 
  background:url("http://lorempixel.com/100/100") center no-repeat ;
  background-size:100px 100px; 
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 15px rgba(100,200,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I am working with several divs, they all combines and makes one image, in fact its for a puzzle game, and a little complicated. the method you provided works for fixed width and one div, 
But problem comes when I use percentage for positioning and several divs

Comment: @Towkir  then , take a look at the 2 other options :) , answer edited (outline-offset or inset shadow). i'll go for the box-shadow...

Comment: Please have a look at http://cssdeck.com/labs/puzzle

notice the right bottom corner of the first piece of puzzle. Hope you will understand my problem . Thanks :)

Comment: I have already used box-shadow for other purpose 
border solution would be better :)

Comment: @Towkir it is  Up to you, but if you have your soution, tell us

Comment: I had to accomplish my target using another div inside each piece (or divs) you can check the cssdeck link once again.
thank you all for helping :)

Comment: @Towkir not too sure, : http://cssdeck.com/labs/ls8iaaer what is wrong with the inset box-shadow alternative ?

Comment: notice the blank place ?? there is shadow effect of the other divs, (to make it realistic, ) the fifth (blank) div has a shadow effect of the left and bottom divs, and the top and right side got it from the mainboard inner shadow ,
so , could not use inset for borders :)

Comment: @Towkir okay, but : div.five {
  background: none;
  outline: ;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px black;  
}
 you reset shadow  there. in the cssdeck forked , i removed div.border style (so they are blank) ?? i do not understand or see what's wrong or different  with div.five . border else where is generated via the inset shdow on div.box

Comment: @Towkir i forked again with inside div .border removed and bg color to .five to see it better :) http://cssdeck.com/labs/6bpmhua2

Comment: @GCyrillus I was trying to make it realistic, but in real life puzzle (the blank space never swaps position with the piece you click) in fact,  the blank space is an empty space. But now it looks like there is no blank. rather a grey div is swaping with the clicked one. :) and the actual darker background appears while swapping process

Comment: @Towkir i don't get it, how is that blank space is suppose to be looking ? bg on demo is only to show better  effect of other boxe's shadows

Comment: In fact I want the .five (div) to appear like there is nothing on that space, so I removed border, bg color or shadows :)
pls see my link again, I changed a little :) thanks GCyrillus.

Answer (score 1):

use outline instead of border

```
div { 
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("someplace/demo.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.classname {
    outline: 2px solid red;
}`

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_outline-offset.asp